# StructureMap 2.6.1, an IRepository<T> and a EFRepository<T,TContext>

Tags: generics, structuremap

So I thought I'd be slick and try this.  I need to pass around a context without newing it up every time AND be able to define the mappings (Entity framework) -- in order to do this I need to inherit then override the DbContext class.  I'd like to keep it plugable with any context I toss in so that's what led me to this.  I got a IRepository interface that takes a  (entity) with your usual suspects in it, and an implementation of it with a dependency on IContextFactory ...

```
public interface IContextFactory<T> where T : DbContext
{
    T Context { get; }
}
```

And on my "EFRepository"

```
public class EFRepository<T, TContext> : IRepository<T> where T : class
        where TContext : DbContext
{

    public EFRepository(IContextFactory<TContext> contextFactory)
    {
    }
}
```

In my mapping, I did one of these jobs ...

```
        x.For(typeof(IContextFactory<>)).Use(typeof(ContextFactory<>));
        x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EFRepository<,>));
```

Ok cool.  In my unit tests, I try it this way...

```
        var repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<EFRepository<Currency, EFContext>>();
        var repository2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Currency>>();
```

First one works, no problem.  2nd one, I get hit with

*The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
Parameter name: instantiation*

I'm guessing it's because I'm not telling structuremap which generic to pass on to IRepository since I'm passing 2?  How do I do that?  ...can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible but it's really messy... unless someone knows of a better way.

First you need to change how you create `EFRepository<,>`. Using the `.Use(context => ...)` overload you can access the context like `context.BuildStack.Current.RequestedType.GetGenericArguments()` to get the generic type you want to access. Then you can new up new instance of `EFRepository<,>` using reflection and getting the `IContextFactory` from the context.

So regardless, something like

```
            ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For(typeof(IContextFactory<>)).Use(typeof(ContextFactory<>));
                x.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(context =>
                    {
                        Type arg1 = context.BuildStack.Current.RequestedType.
                            GetGenericArguments()[0];

                        Type targetType =
                            typeof (EfRepository<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] {arg1, typeof (IContextFactory<>)});

                        return Activator.CreateInstance(targetType,
                                                        new[] {context.GetInstance(typeof (IContextFactory<>))});

                    });
                //x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EfRepository<,>));
            });

        var repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<EfRepository<Currency, EfContext>>();
        var repository2 = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<Currency>>();
```

Will get you most of the way there. I think you still need to properly set the generic for the second generic parameter of targetType before it will work though.

Comment: so the real answer is "this sucks do it another way" ... I'm down with that!  I'll leave the question open for now but this might be the right answer.  And you're right, it does suck. :-(