# ASP.NET MVC - is it okay to have sideline presentation logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In most documentation you read about ASP.NET MVC, the entire 'Separation of Concerns' is very heavily pushed. Dependency Injection/Inversion of Control, Unit Testing, keeping 'logic' out of the Views, etc.

But how far is this intended to be pushed? Is it bad practice if a specific task requires extra logic beyond the 'three layer' approach of View/Model/Persistence?

For example, I have a solution set up with four individual projects.

```
Project.Web (ASP.NET MVC) [ References Data.dll, Models.dll ]
Project.Data (Fluent nHibernate Mapping) [ References Models.dll ]
Project.Models (POCO, Helpers, Factories, etc)
Project.Tests (Unit Testing)
```

Up until now, this has served me pretty well. But I require some very abstract logic for some of my MVC Views, such that I need to take part of the `Models` and arrange a `View Model` that is persisted in the database.

This cannot happen in my `Data` section, as that would dispose the re-usability of it, and there is business logic included in the process. It cannot entirely happen in my `Models` section, because that would require it to have knowledge of the `Data` section, which it does not. And I do not want to put it in the `Web` section because I don't want data access code there.

### Question

Is it in massive violation for me to add, say, a `Project.Presentation` project that references `Data.dll` and `Models.dll` to construct what I need to? Moreover project concerns aside, is this a bad approach in general or is this something a lot of you find yourselves having to do at times? Part of me feels that if I am having to resort to this, then I've just built my software wrong - but at the same time I am very confident I have done a fairly good job, it is just too abstract to make a raw HTML interpretation of without middle-man arrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been my experience that single responsibility is a great way to write code you expect to change early and often.  Like Jan, I too have a solid line between who does what, when.  The more you enforce this, the easier it is to replace an slice of your system.  I recently removed linq2sql with EF4.1 and because of SRP, once I got the tests passing around my new EF4 layer, everything else just worked.

That said, I typically let unit testing dictate where these things live -- it's my driver for SRP as well as asking the basic question "must =class/service= know about =something else= to do it's job?"  If the answer is no, it goes somewhere else -- if yes, it's a dependency.  Now, if it becomes painful, that's its way of telling me "this is stupid" ([see this question for the stupid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943454/structuremap-2-6-1-an-irepositoryt-and-a-efrepositoryt-tcontext)) and I've attempted to force something instead of allowing it to fit the way it must.

Onto your core queston : you've clearly identified a gap in your code -- it MUST know about two things (data and model) and I agree, it should be its own thing and pulled out.  I would call this a "DomainService" or maybe just DTO, but presentation feels like it would be doing more than just prepping data. (I'd argue the view handles the presentation ... maybe you simlpy mean presenter?).  I would also argue against your perception that you did "something wrong" - no, you're learning to write code differently and allowing it to evolving, **EXACTLY** as it should. :-)

Comment: I think this best addresses what I am worried about. I know how to 'solve' the problem, but I've been hesitant to take the approach due to my concerns about how it might violate the design structure.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following structure, which more or less solves all problems we've had regarding MVC structures.

- Models: contains all ViewModels. Just clean, only getters and setters.
- Business logic implementation: Set of projects that contains database logic, DAL entities etc. But only has one interface (in our case this is a WCF API).
- ServiceLayer: the bridge between Business Logic and ViewModels. Doesn't know anything about web.
- Mapping layer: translation between business entities and ViewModels.
- Web project: holds very thin Controllers and Views, and everything web related.

A web page flow will follow this flow:

- URL maps to a certain Action
- Actions are really clean, they only reference a method in the ServiceLayer
- The ServiceLayer executes one or more actions in the Business Logic Implementation (get data, store data, etc.)
- The ServiceLayer passes the business entities to the Mapping Layer.
- The Mapping Layer translates business entities into ViewModels

In code this would look like:

```
// action
public ActionResult ListOfObjects () {
    var model = new ServiceLayer.ObjectsClient().GetListOfObjects();
    return View(model);
}

// Service Layer
public ListOfObjectsModel GetListOfObjects () {
    var businessEntities = BusinessDao.GetThingysFromDb();

    var model = Mapper.TranslateToViewModel(businessEntities);

    return model;
}

// Mapping Layer
public ListOfObjectsModel TranslateToViewModel(List<BusinessEntity> entities) {
    // do mapping
}
```

---

When handling POSTs you will follow the same flow, but the mapping layer should translate your ViewModel into Data Entities that are given to the Business Logic.

Comment: I don't think this answered the question at all.  He has a pretty specific problem that you didn't address.  - Also having the Service Layer assemble viewmodels means it does know about the web/ui piece.  Thats really really really bad and should never be done.  Let your controllers map to viewmodels.  I'm surprised at the upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

"take part of the Models and arrange a View Model that is persisted in the database"

Then its not a viewmodel.

Does that simplify things?

Answer (score 0):

**What is a 'ViewModel':**

More than often 'ViewModel' is confused with persistence. If you look at the word more closely it is a combination of 'View' + 'Model' - which essentially  means it is a single unit of data that is required to fulfill all the needs of your view. A ViewModel can infer multiple entities or sources to build what is required by the View.

**Now Coming to your question:**

Is it in massive violation for me to add, say, a Project.Presentation project that references Data.dll and Models.dll to construct what I need to?

Re: If I had to do it, I would have created a seperate namespace (folder) in my MVC project named 'ViewModels' and placed all my Viewmodels in there. In my opinion if you want your ViewModels to be in a separate namespace, it would not actually violate MVC. You are just incresing the separation or making it more unit test friendly.

Just my 2 cents!!!